# Using iOS SimpleAuth

Tags: ios, facebook, authorization

I am trying to configure an app to use social accounts for login (twitter,facebook, and G+) I am using SimpleAuth from this [GitHub](https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth) first with Facebook, I have created an account and register my bundle Identifier, then I got my app_id from facebook and provided that to the configuration

```
SimpleAuth.configuration[@"facebook"] = @{@"app_id":@"1075396712543857"};
```

Then I called the auth function after clicking a menu item:

```
[SimpleAuth authorize:@"facebook" completion:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"\nResponse: %@\nError:%@", responseObject, error);
```

But I receive this error from the API

```
2016-07-27 18:56:58.982 Deals[6922:2710218] 
Response: (null)
Error:Error Domain=SimpleAuthErrorDomain Code=102 "(null)" UserInfo=
{NSUnderlyingError=0x156852770 {Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The 
Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Error validating access 
token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the 
user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook 
has changed the session for security reasons. (452)" UserInfo=
{NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access 
request: Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored 
session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the 
session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons. 
(452)}}}
```

Can anyone please point me to what I am doing wrong, or if there is another tool that can be used to achieve social login

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

@Mhand7 You need to login first to the facebook. Go to Settings->click Facebook-> and give ur login id and password. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: why i got -1? i have tried this answer and it worked.